# Asp MVC binding calculated results from jQuery to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.

I have textboxes and I have a control that displays the calculated value of the sum of these textboxes.  I use jQuery to calculate these results.

I am struggling with post back, then the total is cleared and I don't know how it can retain the calculated results.  So I thought that if I have a property in my view model then it will retain the value on post back.  I tried using Html.TextboxFor for the total and this seems to hold the value when I click the submit button.  But I don't want it to be a textbox, just text, but I still need it to be bound to the view model.

Part of my view model:

```
public class EditGrantApplicationViewModel
{
   public decimal? GrossMonthlySalary { get; set; }
   public decimal? SpouseGrossMonthlySalary { get; set; }
   public decimal? AdditionalIncome { get; set; }
   public decimal? ChildSupportIncome { get; set; }
   public decimal? TotalMonthlyIncome
   {
      get { return totalMonthlyIncome; }
      set
      {
         totalMonthlyIncome = GrossMonthlySalary +
            SpouseGrossMonthlySalary +
            AdditionalIncome +
            ChildSupportIncome;
      }
   }
}
```

Part of my HTML:

```
<td><label>Gross Monthly Salary:</label> <span class="red">**</span></td>
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.GrossMonthlySalary, new { @class = "income", maxlength = "10", size = "20" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.GrossMonthlySalary)
</td>

<td><label>Spouse Gross Monthly Salary:</label></td>
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SpouseGrossMonthlySalary, new { @class = "income", maxlength = "10", size = "20" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SpouseGrossMonthlySalary)
</td>

<td><label>Any Additional Income:</label></td>
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AdditionalIncome, new { @class = "income", maxlength = "10", size = "20" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.AdditionalIncome)
</td>

<td><label>Child Support Received:</label></td>
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ChildSupportIncome, new { @class = "income", maxlength = "10", size = "20" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ChildSupportIncome)
</td>

<td><label class="total">Total Monthly Income:</label></td>
<td>
   <label id="TotMonthlyIncome" class="total-amount">@Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.TotalMonthlyIncome)</label>
   @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TotalMonthlyIncome)
</td>
```

jQuery for the additions:

```
$('.income').keyup(function () {

   var incomes = $('.income'),
      totDisplay = $('#TotMonthlyIncome'),
      totalDisplay = $('#TotalMonthlyIncome'),
      totalVal = 0;

   incomes.each(function () {
      var matches = null;
      // find the number to add to total
      matches = $(this).val().match(/\d+/);
      // not bothering with the regex on totalVal because we set it
      totalVal = (matches !== null ? parseInt(matches[0], 10) : 0) + parseInt(totalVal, 10);
   });
   totalVal = totalVal === 0 ? '' : totalVal;
   totDisplay.text(totalVal);
   $('#TotalMonthlyIncome').val(totalVal);
});
```

When I type in a value in a textbox then it calculates correctly.  If I type in values in the 4 textboxes then it is calculated correctly.  If I enter a value into on 1 of the textboxes then the TotalMonthlyIncome is null, but when all 4 textboxes have values in it then it has the value of the additions of the textboxes.  Why is it doing this?  Is it something that is not right in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the setter of the `TotalMonthlyIncome` property you must take into account that your decimals could be null:

```
private decimal? totalMonthlyIncome;
public decimal? TotalMonthlyIncome
{
    get { return totalMonthlyIncome; }
    set
    {
        totalMonthlyIncome =
            (GrossMonthlySalary.HasValue ? GrossMonthlySalary.Value : 0m) +
            (SpouseGrossMonthlySalary.HasValue ? SpouseGrossMonthlySalary.Value : 0m) +
            (AdditionalIncome.HasValue ? AdditionalIncome.Value : 0m) +
            (ChildSupportIncome.HasValue ? ChildSupportIncome.Value : 0m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The HasValue and Value properties is this just for nullable types?

Comment: @Brendan Vogt, it's only for the `System.Nullable<T>` type which is what you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You could create hidden input and bind it with viewmodel property.

```
<%: Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CalculatedValue) %>
<div id="DisplayCalculatedValue"><%: Model.CalculatedValue %></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var value = // calculate it
$('#CalculatedValue').val(value);
$('#DisplayCalculatedValue').html(value);
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is not going to work.  I need to display the calculated results as what the user types in the textboxes.  I do this via jQuery.  Your second line of code just displays the value, I need it to be calculated on the fly.

Comment: @Brendan Vogt, you could adapt your jQuery code so that in addition to updating the displayed value it would update the hidden field value as well.

Comment: @Darin but the issue then is that it looses the value at postback. Have you got some sample code for me?  The totals is just for display to the user, I don't save it to the database.  I just thought that by binding the totals to the model will make it keep it's state.

Comment: Just like @Darin Dimitrov said, you should update hidden field with calculated value. This was obvious to me. I guess I should have been more specific. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Darin: What is happening here, I'm not getting this to work properly.  I have updated my original post.